# LWC Get Contact Name for current User (Community User) using wire and importing reference via relationship

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm trying to get the First Name of the  Contact related to the logged-in user.

In [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/288641/70936) have been able to get the contact ID but when I try to import a reference to a field via a relationship I get

> Invalid reference User.ContactId.FirstName of type sobjectField in file

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from "lwc";
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from "lightning/uiRecordApi";
import CONTACT_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/User.ContactId.FirstName";
import USER_ID from "@salesforce/user/Id";


export default class LogoAndApplicantName extends LightningElement {


  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: USER_ID, fields: [CONTACT_NAME] })
  user;

  get contactName() {
    return getFieldValue(this.user.data, CONTACT_NAME);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to reference a relationship field based on Contact lookup, try this instead :

```
import CONTACT_NAME from "@salesforce/schema/User.Contact.FirstName";
```